# Looping through curl requests

Tags: php, curl

EDIT: I resolved this, below is the code in case it is helpful to someone in the future:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$value);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiUser . ":" . $apiKey); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $fileResponse = "responses/".( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    $current = file_get_contents($fileResponse);
    $current .= $result ."\r\n";
    file_put_contents($fileResponse, $current);
    $responseHeader = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
}
```

I have been digging through the site and have found a few similar questions but none that are quite right. I am something of a beginner so this could be a simple fix.

I am attempting to create a curl script that will loop through a number of http requests using array values. I will be intaking csv files with customer data, creating http requests with this data, then using this script to send each request through an API and get the response. I plan to use each set of array element values as the curl postfields, the array structure is similar to the following:

```
 [0]=>
  array(8) {
    string(4) "bln1"
    ["bfn"]=>
    string(4) "bfn1"
    ["bsn"]=>
    string(4) "bsn1"
    ["bs"]=>
    string(3) "bs1"
    ["bc"]=>
    string(3) "bc1"
    ["bco"]=>
    string(4) "bco1"
    ["tea"]=>
    string(4) "tea1"
    ["man"]=>
    string(4) "man1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["bln"]=>
    string(4) "bln2"
    ["bfn"]=>
    string(4) "bfn2"
    ["bsn"]=>
    string(4) "bsn2"
    ["bs"]=>
    string(3) "bs2"
    ["bc"]=>
    string(3) "bc2"
    ["bco"]=>
    string(4) "bco2"
    ["tea"]=>
    string(4) "tea2"
    ["man"]=>
    string(4) "man2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["bln"]=>
    string(4) "bln3"
    ["bfn"]=>
    string(4) "bfn3"
    ["bsn"]=>
    string(4) "bsn3"
    ["bs"]=>
    string(3) "bs3"
    ["bc"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["bco"]=>
    string(4) "bco3"
    ["tea"]=>
    string(4) "tea3"
    ["man"]=>
    string(4) "man3"
  }
```

I have a working curl request which loops on a specified number (loops=#) but I have been unable to make this work. I would like to avoid curl_multi and send these serially because I want to capture the requests and responses in the same order.

In researching [pass array with list file to curl loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440445/pass-array-with-list-file-to-curl-loop) and [PHP - Read every line in a CSV, take the data and Post/CURL each line one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444118/php-read-every-line-in-a-csv-take-the-data-and-post-curl-each-line-one-by-one) appeared to be very similar to what I want to accomplish, but I was unable to get the script to work.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Code included and edited.

For the loop I have tried both:

```
$count = count($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
```

and:

```
foreach($data as $value) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$value);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiUser . ":" . $apiKey); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $responseHeader = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);
}
```

The array is JSON encoded and looks like the following:

```
[{"bln":"bln1","bfn":"bfn1","bsn":"bsn1","bs":"bs1","bc":"bc1","bco":"bco1","tea":"tea1","man":"man1"},{"bln":"bln2","bfn":"bfn2","bsn":"bsn2","bs":"bs2","bc":"bc2","bco":"bco2","tea":"tea2","man":"man2"},{"bln":"bln3","bfn":"bfn3","bsn":"bsn3","bs":"bs3","bc":"","bco":"bco3","tea":"tea3","man":"man3"}]
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: you need to post the code your using, and it explain what is not working in it

Comment: you don't use `$key` or `$value` in your code(loop) - so im confused as what your doing here

Comment: I am trying to create a loop using the array values as the curl postfields but am obviously not doing it correctly. I do not have much experience with this and was hoping to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: what are the required post fields?

Comment: It will depend on the file that contains the data. The files are expected to have the api param/key in the header and the values below and another script is generating an array based on the contents. Each array element could vary.

Comment: Since the array is already key:value would looping on the array element count be a better route to explore?